# How to install phalcon 3.2 on windows10

Tags: php, xampp, phalcon

I tried to install phalcon 3.2 with phalcon git.
But there is no details about windows environment.
  How to install phalcon to xampp server on windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the phalcon from [official site](https://phalconphp.com/en/)
2. Extract the downloaded archive and copy `php_phalcon.dll` file to your xampp's `php/ext` directory
3. Edit the `php.ini` file located at `C:\xampp\php\php.ini.` and add the line `extension=php_phalcon.dll` at the end of the file.
4. Restart apache server and you're good to go.

Comment: I tried that following the steps but not sure why phalcon is not listed in phpinfo :(

Comment: My mistake, I downloaded the wrong version of phalcon for my xampp, I downloaded for php7.0.0 and it should have been for php7.1.0